# How to 'RUN' Zero-Argument Function in SML

Tags: function, sml

If there were a function *foo* like this:

```
fun foo() = 10
```

When I want to run the *foo*, I wrote like this:

```
val bar = foo
```

But *bar* becomes a function (unit->int) not 10

So I tried like this:

```
val int bar = foo
```

But it makes error. So I tried like this:

```
fun foo x = 10

val bar = foo 0
```

Finally I get *bar* = 10, but it looks horrible.

So, what should I do for *run* the zero-argument function without change anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be thinking of some other languages, where `()` would mean an empty parameter list.
In SML, it doesn't.

`foo` doesn't take zero arguments; it takes exactly one argument: `()`.

```
- fun foo () = 10;
val foo = fn : unit -> int
```

As you can see, `foo` is a function from `unit` to `int`.

```
- ();
val it = () : unit
```

`()` (usually pronounced "unit") is the only value of the `unit` type.
(The word "unit" can mean "a single thing", which is exactly what the type is.)

To call the function, pass it an argument of type `unit`:

```
- foo ();
val it = 10 : int
```

You can of course also bind a name to `()`:

```
- val kittens = ();
val kittens = () : unit
- foo kittens;
val it = 10 : int
```

Side note: you may think this is odd if you compare to, say,

```
- fun bar (x,y) = x + y;
val bar = fn : int * int -> int
```

but `bar` also takes just one argument, of type `int * int`.
We usually *say* that it takes two, but from the type system's point of view there is only one argument (which is a pair).